# UIImageView and vector images: how to adjust for zooming to avoid blurry image

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiimageview

I have a vector image named Link in my asset catalog (in my case contained in a pdf, setup as preserve vector data) and I use an `UIImageView` to show this image in my view hierarchy:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Link")
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.image = image
```

And this is the simple view hierarchy:
[image: view hierarchy]
As you can see I use `.scaleAspectFit` and when I set a frame for `imageView` the UIImageView renders the image in the desired resolution to look sharp on screen. So far so good.

In order to zoom an scroll I use an `UIScrollView`. After zooming in the image in the `imageView` appears blurry due to obviously having too low resolution for the higher zoom:
[image]

**Is there any straight forward way to adjust UIImageView so that it renders the image in a higher resolution?**

Discussion:

- Using `.scaleAspectFit` the renderered image resolution resolution seems to depend on the frame set for `imageView`. So setting a bigger frame and scaling the view using its transform property works, but is also rather tedious.
- Another way is manually rendering the image at an apporpriate solution from the vector image using `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` or similar. This is currenlty my preferred solution, but I am wondering if there is an easier way using `UIImageView`.

Here is sample code (just replace your main ViewController with this in a new project), which shows the blurry image when zooming in (just use any vector image named Link in your assets and choose render as "Template Image"):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    let contentView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1000.0, height: 1000.0))
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let view = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 400.0, height: 400.0))
        view.minimumZoomScale = 0.5
        view.maximumZoomScale = 10.0
        return view
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.scrollView.delegate = self
        
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
        
        // setup view hierarchy
        self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(self.contentView)
        // constraints
        self.scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        self.scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        self.scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        self.contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        self.contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10.0 * self.view.frame.width).isActive = true
        self.contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10.0 * self.view.frame.height).isActive = true
        
        // setup imageView
        let image = UIImage(named: "Link")
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.tintColor = UIColor.black
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        // add constraints
        imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        let zoomScale = 8.0
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.5 * (self.contentView.frame.width - self.scrollView.frame.width), y: 0.5 * (self.contentView.frame.height - self.scrollView.frame.height))
        self.scrollView.zoomScale = zoomScale
    }
    
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return self.contentView
    }
}
```

Comment: Bit of a hacky idea but you could set the size of your UIImageView to be 10x bigger (because of your 10x zoom on the scrollView) and then apply a scale effect to it so it's the right size. Like `transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)`. The center can stay the same. Haven't tested but maybe that's an easy way to get it to render at the resolution you want?

Comment: @Miles: Yes, that is one thing I menitioned above. But it seems a bit hacky and I was wondering if `UIImageView` does have functionality to do that. I was thinking of setting `contentScaleFactor` or something like that, but that does not have any effect in my case.

Comment: @Wizard - are you trying to zoom your SVG image only? Or, will it be one of several UI elements that are subviews of your "content view"?

Comment: @DonMag: It is the latter. `imageView` is a subview of the `contentView` of my `scrollView`. I updated the question above with the view hierarchy to make this more clear.